# How to run a python flask application on https from EC2 machine on HTTPS

Tags: python-3.x, flask, amazon-ec2

I have written a small python application using `flask`. I have deployed the application on EC2 machine. Currently the application run as `http`. I want the application on `https`. How can I do it? instead of doing any modification in code like adding `ssl_context`?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to be touching `ssl_context`. What you are trying to do is to just run your web server over HTTPS.

Depending on the web server you have (Nginx, Apache etc.), this is just a case of getting/generating a SSL certificate (you can use [CertBot](https://certbot.eff.org/) for this - this generates certificates via [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)).

Once you have a SSL certificate, you then need to configure your web server to use this SSL certificate (as well as allow HTTPS connections on your firewall settings).

These guides helped me in the past, but you can always look online for a guide that suits the server OS you are using:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04
- https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/

Hope this helps!